# selected accessoryView for specified cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, selected, accessoryview

the question is quite simple. How can you make an accessoryView in a tableView to be "Selected" for each row that has the same title in both section 0 and 1? (iOS)

I want to do this because when I select the accessoryView in a row, the row copies up to a new section 0 which is called "favorites". *But the problem is*, if I deselect the row in section 0, the row disappears but the accessoryView stays selected for the corresponding row in section 1, which I wan't to be deselected in that case. Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)addToFavs:(id)sender event:(id)event {
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    if(indexPath!=nil){
            if(button.selected==YES){
                button.selected = NO;
            }else{
                button.selected =YES;
            }
        [self tableView: self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell){
        // left image
        UIImageView *image=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 7, 30, 30)];

        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
        cell.textLabel.text=self.objects[indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text =self.subtitles[indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:image];

        if(indexPath.section==0){
            image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[self.iconsFavs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            cell.textLabel.text=self.favs[indexPath.row];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text =self.subtitlesFavs[indexPath.row];
        }else{
            image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[self.icons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }
        //favorites image button
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 25, 25);
        button.frame = frame;
        button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unfavorites.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorites.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(addToFavs:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        if(indexPath.section==0){
            button.selected = !button.selected;
        }
        cell.accessoryView.tag=indexPath.row;
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.accessoryView = button;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way to do this, create an array for favorite and add item to this array on select. And select accessory view if the item is in array of favorites.

Comment: Yeah I just got i working with this `if ([self.favs containsObject:[self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {
            button.tag=button.selected=YES;
        }else {
            button.tag =button.selected=NO;
        }
        }`
but it doesn't refresh directly, how can I fix that?

Comment: are you reloading cell after this...? better way will be when you keep slecect a cell you must reload it... you can do this by  [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

Comment: I put it in the if(cell) block in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: That what I am saying, you are selecting accessory view in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and this will be called only when you cell is loading. So now if you are on select and deselct row at indexPath you should call reloadCellForRowAtIndexPath, then It will execute your logic and will select accessory view or will deselect accessory view.